# How to tell what components are compatible with Arduino Due?

Tags: motor, arduino-due, electronics, solar

I am interested in using the [Arduino Due](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue) in an upcoming project, however I am worried that the other shields/components that I need will not be compatible with it, because, according to that link:

> The Due is compatible with all Arduino shields that work at 3.3V and are compliant with the 1.0 Arduino pinout.

The components I need to use are:

- NightShade Electronics [energyShield](http://www.ns-electric.com/products/energyshield/)
- [Solar Panel](http://www.adafruit.com/products/200)
- [Servo Motors](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1143?gclid=CjwKEAjw96aqBRDNhM6MtJfE-wYSJADiMfgguI7rTduiPEzHwVkcWxKifp1IMtwpI6VHO8btHORRKBoCStHw_wcB)

Essentially a solar panel will power the energyShield (rechargeable battery), which in turn will power multiple servo motors.

I cannot tell if the energyShield uses the 1.0 pinout or not. I am also worried that since the the solar power generates 6V it will overload the energyShield which is rated at 3.3V. At the same time, I am worried that the servo motors, which seem to require 4.8V, will not be capable of being powered by the energyShield which outputs 3.3V. Thoughts?

Bonus Points if someone can explain to me what the "1.0 Pinout" is, and whether it is the latest/most modern pinout available for Arduinos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood this energyShiled accepts any input between 5-24V and output 5 - 3.3V. This specs are compatible with arduino Due. And with the solar panel.

You can always power servos from seperate source or from the same battery but with seperate direct line.